# How can i run my sql code without the time range error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, runtime-error

I have a code like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fnSublocacaoGerencialNew(NULL/*DataInicial*/, NULL/*DataFinal*/, Null/*NrSublocacaoEspecifico*/) 
ORDER BY NrSublocacao DESC
```

When I select a date like `17/10/2023` or `17-10-2023` and put some other value for the final date I have the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fnSublocacaoGerencialNew(10/10/2023, 17/10/2023, Null/*NrSublocacaoEspecifico*/) 
ORDER BY NrSublocacao DESC
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM fnSublocacaoGerencialNew(10-10-2023, 17-10-2023, Null/*NrSublocacaoEspecifico*/) 
ORDER BY NrSublocacao DESC
```

I expected a table with that range, but I didn't get it. How can I fix this?

Comment: `10/10/2023` isn't a date, it's an `int`; specifically `0`. `10/10/2023 = 1 / 2023 = 0` It's a similar story for `10-10-2023`; `10-10-2023 = 0-2023 = -2023`. Use an unambiguous date format for dates, such as `20231017`.

Comment: You can also use the built-in function [datefromparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) if you don't want to mess with string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Different cultures and languages have different expectations around how dates should be formatted. When talking to someone from a different culture in their own language, you should be sure to communicate with them using the date formats of that language.

The SQL language is no different. Regardless of how you normally format dates, when writing SQL code you should use the date format the language expects, rather than your own. For SQL Server, that format is `yyyyMMdd`: year, then month, then day, with no hyphen or slash separators.

Additionally, you need to put the the date literals in single quotes. So we end up with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fnSublocacaoGerencialNew('20231010', '20231017', Null/*NrSublocacaoEspecifico*/) 
ORDER BY NrSublocacao DESC
```

There are other formats that might *seem* to work, or will work well with *most* common default culture settings for specific server installation or database locale configurations, but this is the format that is guaranteed to work **everywhere** with SQL Server.